# Provide a link from completed election pages to OpaVote

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, election

After an election ends, the election page has a section that [looks something like this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/election/3):

[image: election results text]

But what is this silliness about *downloading* some *desktop app* and *installing it*? It's 2013 and this is **the internet**; we can do better than this!

What we can do is point people at https://instantstv.appspot.com/. What we can do *even better* is to have a link that goes to https://instantstv.appspot.com/ **with the relevant results passed along already**.

This would, I suspect, increase the number of people who *actually look* at the election process dramatically. Thich would be a good thing.

---

***edit*** to add:

Something like this appears to already be happening! These days, [meta posts *about* election results](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5701/2013-community-moderator-election-results) now (perhaps only sometimes?) include something like this:

> For details on how the voting played out, you can download the
>   election results
>   [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a
>   summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/958001/0).

That latter link is to OpaVote, which provides exactly what I'm after.

**Could we have a link from the *election page* to OpaVote please?**

Comment: Black-box algorithms and implementations are opaque, insecure and anti-democratic. OpaVote actually forked from OpenSTV , which was open source until version 1.7. We should ideally tally using that or some other open source software. If that is too much of a hassle, we should at least point people to whatever software we're aware of which likely would reproduce the round-by-round results, and ask them to audit the results. This might work: https://github.com/Conservatory/openstv

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Employees now have the ability to add a link to the OpaVote results:

[image: Super User election #4 results]

At the moment, filling in the [OpaVote result ID](https://www.opavote.com/help/overview#results) is a manual step for whoever (me) wraps up an election. The data hasn't been backfilled for older elections, but it probably could be (assuming I have some time and motivation). For elections that have no result ID filled in, there is no link to the online results.

In the future, I hope to have the election announcement automated using the [OpaVote API](https://www.opavote.com/help/api). That would save a number of manual steps and allow us to announce the results nearly instantly.

Comment: Thank you.  It's a hassle to find the corresponding meta post for an election in order to find that link in order to view the results.  If somebody wrote a query to find the URLs on meta for you, would that make it any easier to backfill?  Or do you already have that and it's the actual editing that'll take your time and motivation?

Comment: @MonicaCellio: I can get the URLs relatively easily. The trick is entering them into the database. I can do it by hand, but I think I'm going to write a series for SQL UPDATE statements instead. (Then I'll need to get a dev with database access to run them.)

Answer (score 6):

I second the request and while I guess that it’s very easy to implement anyway, I would like to draw attention to the following motivation:

Transparency is an important feature of elections it allows people to control and understand that the results aren’t random or otherwise flawed. This applies in particular to Stack Exchange’s election system, which is more advanced but also more complicated than regular elections. Obstructing the access to detailed election results by only linking the version that requires downloading and understanding some software may thus nurture a user’s dissatisfaction and desinterest with the elections and the elected moderators, which in turn is obviously detrimental to the community.

Thus an easy and direct access to the election results should be available on all related pages and posts, not just the announcement on Meta.